# SwiftUI - Saving ARRAY into NSSet

Tags: arrays, core-data, swiftui, nsset

I'am having trouble with adding an Array [Categories] into my Questions entity relationship

[image]

The categories relationship being a "to many" it is an NSSet, so I would like to add my [Categories] array into this NSSet.

I have tried  something like this, but nothing gets in.

`newQuestion.categories?.addingObjects(from: self.selections)`

self.selection being an Array of

Thanks for your help.

Tim

Comment: You don't need to do it , because you can save an index with each Categories and later to sort them by the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following instead of that line

```
if let categories = newQuestion.categories {
    newQuestion.categories = categories.addingObjects(from: self.selections)
} else {
    newQuestion.categories = Set(self.selections)
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I just needed to add: ```as NSSet``` but it works fine, Thank you. If I understood correctly the point of this is to extract the NSSet as a Set, into which we'll add the Array? ```if let categoriesToSAve = newQuestion.categories {
                            newQuestion.categories = categoriesToSAve.addingObjects(from: self.selections) as NSSet
                        } else {
                            newQuestion.categories = Set(self.selections) as NSSet
                        }```

Comment: @Tim, not only, initially it might be nil, so it needs to create it.